# SQL Server Nested Cursors and Variables Declaration

Tags: sql-server, variables, cursors

I have a doubt regarding the variable declaration in a nested cursors scenario.

This is an small nested cursor sample that i found. In other samples I've seen I also find DECLARE clauses inside the first cursor.

```
DECLARE @ClientID int;
DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT ClientID From Folder;
OPEN Cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ClientID;
SELECT @FETCH_Cur1 = @@FETCH_STATUS
WHILE @FETCH_Cur1 = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @UID int;
    DECLARE Cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT UID FROM Attend Where ClientID=@ClientID;
    OPEN Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @UID;
    SELECT @FETCH_Cur2 = @@FETCH_STATUS
    WHILE @FETCH_Cur2 = 0
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'Found UID: ' + Cast(@UID as Varchar);
        
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @UID;
        SELECT @FETCH_Cur2 = @@FETCH_STATUS
    END;
    CLOSE Cur2;
    DEALLOCATE Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ClientID;
    SELECT @FETCH_Cur1 = @@FETCH_STATUS
END;
PRINT 'DONE';
CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;
```

The code works, but my doubt is if it's correct the DECLARATIONS inside the first cursor.

```
DECLARE @UID int;
```

Shouldn't Declarations be placed at the beginning of code, as is normally done for other programming languages?

Comment: Of course, though a different question, the real question is why are you using a cursor in the first place, when SQL is a set based language.

Comment: Obvioulsy, this is not a scenario for using nested cursors, it was just a simplified sample. But sometimes I need to use them, for example, if i want to call an external sp for each record, etc...

Comment: Write code (of any language) that clearly expresses its goal and is easily understood. Follow those rules and you should have no doubts. Just because you can do some things doesn't mean you should. Using tricky scoping rules only makes code more difficult to understand and more difficult to change / correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* `DECLARE` a variable inside a `WHILE`, yes; the latter `DECLARE`s will simply be ignored. If you declared the variable and assigned it a value at the time (for example `DECLARE @UID int = 1;` it would be assigned `1` in each iteration:

```sql
DECLARE @I int = 1;

WHILE @i < 10 BEGIN

    DECLARE @W int;

    SET @W = ISNULL(@W,1) + 1;

    SET @I = @I + 1
END

SELECT @W; --10
GO

DECLARE @I int = 1;

WHILE @i < 10 BEGIN

    DECLARE @W int = 0;

    SET @W = ISNULL(@W,1) + 1;

    SET @I = @I + 1
END

SELECT @W; -- 1
```

[DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b02782c7529b87e469fb368f9e88bd20)

Of course, I personally prefer to `DECLARE` the variables outside of the `WHILE` as I feel the code is "cleaner", but that doesn't mean you have to.